# Force landscape orientation in one view controller

Tags: ios7, autorotate

In iOS 5 and 6 I was doing this in the viewWillAppear method in my view controller:

```
UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
//To avoid the warning complaining about the view not being part of the window hierarchy
[[[TWNavigationManager shared] window] addSubview:c.view];
[self presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[c.view removeFromSuperview];
```

I also added this method in the app delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application      supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return [[TWNavigationManager shared] supportedInterfaceOrientationsForTopViewController];
}
```

Which basically forwards that call to the top view controller.

That caused auto-rotation methods to be called for my view controller and then I was able to force landscape orientation for just that view controller.
Now in iOS 7 that code doesn't work anymore. A white view appears full-screen.

What would be the proper approach in iOS7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you present this lanscape-only-viewController from ? Is it a 'push' in a navigation stack ? Or a viewcontroller presented modally ? (in which case it's easier)

Comment: Yes, it's a push in the navigation stack. My root view controller is a UITabBarViewController and each item has a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and managed to fix it by dismissing the presented modal view animated:YES.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves what Andrey Finayev suggested, but also I had to set another transition style otherwise I was getting blank screen after the dismiss animation finished.

```
UIViewController *mVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
mVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
mVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mVC animated:NO completion:^{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the little "flashing" from mdonia solution, I added a dispatch_after and was able to dismiss the dummy modal viewController with animation:NO

```
UIViewController *dummyModalVC = [UIViewController new];
[dummyModalVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[dummyModalVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[dummyModalVC.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

[self presentViewController:dummyModalVC animated:NO completion:^{
    double delayInSeconds = 0.001f;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [dummyModalVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
    });
}];
```

Looks of course still like an ugly workaround, but I didn't found a better solution in the given time… ;(